# Service Worker not working when hosted, but works on localhost

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I'm working on a PWA and I'm facing an issue with the service worker and I can't figure out what's wrong.

So when I run the lighthouse audit on localhost, it passes every criteria except for the HTTPS one. You can view it below;
[image]

However, when I publish the code to my github pages, and run the same audit there, the service worker is never activated. It gives me the error. The status becomes 'redundant' when I run the audit online.
Link: https://ibr4h1m.github.io/MAD5/index.html

Below I'll show the code, which is the exact same on the website that I've mentioned above.

main.js:

```
//Simple ServiceWorker
if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
};
```

sw.js

```
const cacheName = 'tourguide-site';
const appShellFiles =  ['index.html',
    'help.html',
    'destinations.html',
    'contact.html',
    'js/main.js',
    'css/style.css',
    'sw.js'
];


self.addEventListener('install', (e) => {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Install');
  e.waitUntil((async () => {
    const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
    console.log('[Service Worker] Caching all: app shell and content');
    await cache.addAll(appShellFiles);
  })());
});


// Simple Activate since the other one is BS

self.addEventListener('activate', function () {
  console.log('SW Activated');
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {
  e.respondWith((async () => {
    const r = await caches.match(e.request);
    console.log(`[Service Worker] Fetching resource: ${e.request.url}`);
    if (r) { return r; }
    const response = await fetch(e.request);
    const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
    console.log(`[Service Worker] Caching new resource: ${e.request.url}`);
    cache.put(e.request, response.clone());
    return response;
  })());
});
```

Online audit:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
const appShellFiles =  ['index.html',
    'help.html',
    'destinations.html',
    'contact.html',
    'js/main.js',
    'css/style.css',
    'sw.js'
];
```

Remove the `sw.js` from your appShellFiles